# How to pair the content of a list of numbers after binning

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
a = range(1,20)
x = np.histogram(a, bins=3, range=None, normed=False, weights=None)
bin_members = list(x[1])
bin_members 
# Out[38]: [1.0, 7.0, 13.0, 19.0]
```

My question is how can I print the the number the list in `bin_members`
into this paired form:

```
1 - 6
7 - 12
13 - 19
```

See the [Note of numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) for defining the pairs above.

Comment: do you mean 7 - 12?

Comment: @Eumel you're right. I corrected my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must iterate over each value, and the next, to print them together:

```
import numpy as np 
a = range(1,20)
x = np.histogram(a, bins=3, range=None, normed=False, weights=None)
bin_members = list(x[1])
bin_members
for idx, elt in enumerate(bin_members[:-1]):
    val = int(bin_members[idx+1]) if idx == (len(bin_members)-2) else int(bin_members[idx+1]-1)
    print(f"{int(elt)} - {val}")               # python version >= 3.6
    # print("{} - {}".format(int(elt), val))   # python version < 3.6
```

#### Output:

```
1 - 6
7 - 12
13 - 19
```

Comment: this will come out to 13-18 thoughfor the third line

Comment: @RehlochonMasque I get `invalid syntax` for `print(f"{int(elt)} - {int(bin_members[idx+1]-1)}")`

Comment: If you're using python3.6, don't forget to mention so. @pdubois  fstrings are not available in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested, there's a function that does this for you in `pandas`, using the `IntervalIndex.from_breaks`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(bin_members)

IntervalIndex([(1.0, 7.0], (7.0, 13.0], (13.0, 19.0]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

You could also do this with `pd.cut`:

```
pd.cut(bin_members, bins=bin_members)

[NaN, (1.0, 7.0], (7.0, 13.0], (13.0, 19.0]]
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(1.0, 7.0] < (7.0, 13.0] < (13.0, 19.0]]
```